# Pandas groupby to get an average day

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, aggregate, grouping

I have a dataframe which is the result from reading a csv. It contains a datetime column and data related to an event. I need to calculate an average day with statistical data per 20 minutes, in the code below I use 'mean' as an example.

**Edit:**
*My data are observations. This means that not all bins have data in it. But this zero-counts do have to be taken into account when calculating the mean value: mean = count / #days*

This code works but is this the way to go? It looks to complicated to me and I wonder if I really need to us a BinID and cant't group by time of day.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create dataframe
data = {'date': pd.date_range('2017-01-01 00:30:00', freq='10min', periods=282),
         'i/o': ['in', 'out'] * 141}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Add ones
df['move'] = 1

# I did try:
# 1)
#    df['time'] = df['date'].dt.time
#    df.groupby(['i/o', pd.Grouper(key='time', freq='20min')])
#    This failed with groupby, so should I use my own bins then???

# 2)
#    Create 20 minutes bins
#    df['binID'] = df['date'].dt.hour*3 + df['date'].dt.minute//20
#    averageDay = df.groupby(['i/o', 'binID']).agg(['count', 'sum', 'mean'])
#
#    Well, bins with zero moves aren't their.
#    So 'mean' can't be used as well as other functions that
#    need the number of observations. Resample and reindex then???

# Resample
df2 = df.groupby(['i/o', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='20min')]).agg('sum')

# Reindex and reset (for binID and groupby)
levels = [['in', 'out'],
          pd.date_range('2017-01-01 00:00:00', freq='20min', periods=144)]
newIndex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(levels, names=['i/o', 'date'])
df2 = df2.reindex(newIndex, fill_value=0).reset_index()

# Create 20 minutes bins
df2['binID'] = df2['date'].dt.hour*3 + df2['date'].dt.minute//20

# Average day
averageDay2 = df2.groupby(['i/o', 'binID']).agg(['count', 'sum', 'mean'])
print(averageDay2)
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
In [124]: df.groupby(['i/o',df.date.dt.hour*3 + df.date.dt.minute//20]) \
            .agg(['count','sum','mean'])
Out[124]:
          move
         count sum mean
i/o date
in  0        1   1    1
    1        2   2    1
    2        2   2    1
    3        2   2    1
    4        2   2    1
    5        2   2    1
    6        2   2    1
    7        2   2    1
    8        2   2    1
    9        2   2    1
...        ...  ..  ...
out 62       2   2    1
    63       2   2    1
    64       2   2    1
    65       2   2    1
    66       2   2    1
    67       2   2    1
    68       2   2    1
    69       2   2    1
    70       2   2    1
    71       1   1    1

[144 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: I suppose that I wasn't clear enough. My data are observations. This means that not all bins have data in it. But this zero-counts do have to be taken into account when calculating the mean value: mean = count / #days